# .NET Framework  3.5 build error on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build

I have written a batch script to build .NET code which looks like this:

```
set BUILD_PATH=%CD%

call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

devenv /clean Release "%BUILD_PATH%\Source\Dotnet\WebService\OPALController\OPALController.sln"

devenv /rebuild Release "%BUILD_PATH%\Source\Dotnet\WebService\OPALController\OPALController.sln
```

Which is only working for target framework 4.0, I am getting error during deployment for .NET 3.5

> Server Error in '/P05INOPALDEV' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built
>   by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I am at the beginner stage, can anyone plz help me resolve this

Comment: what's in app_code. More specifically what's in app_code build for .NET v4.0 (answer that and you have answered your own question

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSBuild to compile your solution.
To clean solution use:

```
msbuild /t:clean
```

To build solution use "build" instead of "clean", for rebuild use "rebuild".
By default "Debug" configuration is used, to override this you need to specify value for Configuration property:

```
msbuild /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your IIS setup, I can only imagine that the AppPool you are using to host your service is running the default of .Net 2.0.

Try changing your app pool to run .Net 4.0.

To do this, open IIS Manager, click on the site hosting your service, and open Basic Settings.  There is an Application Pool setting.  Write it down, and then go to Applicition Pools in IIS Manager, and find the AppPool.  My guess this is has a .NET Framework of v2.0.  double click and change to v4.0.